# NSDates are being stored differently when the app is on the App store, but work perfectly when debugging in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, app-store, nsdate

I have made a fitness app that tracks workouts. The workouts are a class that have an NSDate member. This NSDate member (`date`) is used to show progress on a graph. The app does this by fetching all of the previous workouts into a `[Workout]` array, then sorts the workouts by date. The sorting algorithm I previously used was `workouts.sort({$0.date.timeIntervalSinceNow > $1.date.timeIntervalSinceNow})` which worked fine when running on my iPhone with Xcode. When I uploaded the app to the app store and downloaded it, the algorithm sorted all the dates backwards.

When I posted this problem previously, the general suggestion was to change the sort method to:

`workouts.sort({abs($0.date.timeIntervalSince1970) > abs($1.date.timeIntervalSince1970)})`
Which I thought would work, but my app review went through today, and it did not - the problem is exactly the same.

My question is this: How are NSDates being sorted differently when the app is uploaded to the App store?

I ran this app from Xcode and it worked fine. Then I immediately downloaded the app from the app store and the dates were all backwards. How can this be happening? I haven't changed time zones and my phone clock has not changed.

Comment: I don't know what causes the difference in sorting, but I suggest using the `compare` method of NSDate. Also: does this occur also when you run from Xcode using the release scheme?

Comment: @Rengers Thanks for your input. I changed it to the `compare` method and started ran it with the release scheme and it works fine. Will resubmit to app store and hope that this fixes the issue.

Answer (score 2):

```
let yesterday    = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar)!.dateWithEra(1, year: 2015, month: 03, day: 21, hour: 19, minute: 0, second: 0, nanosecond: 0)!
let today        = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar)!.dateWithEra(1, year: 2015, month: 03, day: 22, hour: 19, minute: 0, second: 0, nanosecond: 0)!
let tomorrowDate = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar)!.dateWithEra(1, year: 2015, month: 03, day: 23, hour: 19, minute: 0, second: 0, nanosecond: 0)!
let daysFromNow2 = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar)!.dateWithEra(1, year: 2015, month: 03, day: 24, hour: 19, minute: 0, second: 0, nanosecond: 0)!
let daysFromNow3 = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar)!.dateWithEra(1, year: 2015, month: 03, day: 25, hour: 19, minute: 0, second: 0, nanosecond: 0)!

var myDates:[NSDate] = [tomorrowDate,daysFromNow3,today,yesterday,daysFromNow2]
var sortedArray = myDates.sorted{$0.compare($1) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending}

println(sortedArray)
```